# I have created a lambda function to track slow queries in PostgreSQL to the slack channel

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have created a lambda function to track slow queries in PostgreSQL to the slack channel. I have slow query logs displayed as well. But the problem is we have some logs with only duration and no query details like the example below. Also, we could find the same logs in the postgreSQL-RDS instance as well.

```
@timestamp - 2022-06-29 10:40:18.000
Query - 2022-06-29 10:40:18 UTC:10.102.22.204(55164):staging@staging:[25473]:LOG: duration: 20.212 ms
@duration - 20.212


@timestamp - 2022-06-29 10:23:24.000
Query - 2022-06-29 10:23:24 UTC:10.102.22.204(55162):staging@staging:[12442]:LOG: duration: 1224.268 ms
@duration - 122
```

Please provide a solution either to filter out the logs without query details or how to make those logs to display the query details

Comment: Is this question about a lambda function (which we can't see) or about a logging configuration (which we also can't see)?

Comment: Maybe [this Note](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) starting with "When using this option together with log_statement" applies here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.